What is a direct limit of chain complexes?
As in this post, I have been stuck on exercise 3.3.17 of Hatcher. In particular, the textbook defines a 'direct limit of chain complexes', but what exactly does that mean?
Would deeply appreciate any insight!

It is about a general thing in category theory. It is good to know the basics. For complexes, degreewise you just take the direct limit of the objects of that degree. Look up the direct limit of modules

Direct limits are defined on p. 243. (Look in the index if you’re using a different edition of Hatcher)
